# How to pass HTML via JSON from PHP to AJAX - properly

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm still in AJAX stuff since morning so maybe thats the reason why some things does't work as they schould - let's forget about it. To sum up, my problem is coincident with passing HTML via JSON. An example of the PHP code:

```
$list = "<strong>This is test</strong>";
$response = array('success'=>true, 'src' => $list);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Basicly that's the main part of the code which is responsible for passing the HTML to AJAX. Now, let's have a look on part of AJAX code:

```
            success: function(output)
            {
                alert(output);
                json = $(output).find(".content").text();
                var data = $.parseJSON(json);
                if(data.success == true)
                {
                   obj_a.parents(".row").append(data.src);
                   obj_a.attr("id", "rollBack");
                   obj_a.text("Roll back");
                }
            },
```

Some of you will ask what am I doing in this part:

```
json = $(output).find(".content").text();
```

The answer is: I retrieve the json string from the ".content" box, so when I alert variable "json: i get:

```
{"success":true,"src":"1. dsfasdfasdffbcvbcvb<\/span>Edytuj<\/span> <\/a>Usu \u0144<\/span><\/div>2. vbnvbnm454t<\/span>Edytuj<\/span><\/a>Usu\u0144<\/span><\/div>3. ndfhgndgfhndfhgndfhd<\/span>Edytuj<\/span><\/a>Usu\u0144<\/span><\/div><\/div>"}
```

The problem is that I do not get this HTML... I get only text witout any HTML tags, styles etc...

String which I get, rather than HTML:
"1. dsfasdfasdffbcvbcvbEdytujUsuń2. vbnvbnm454tEdytujUsuń3. ndfhgndgfhndfhgndfhdEdytujUsuń"

Please don't try to look for anything smart or gunius in the above string because u won't - it's only a test string.

Acording to the part of PHP code - in my case I get "This is test" rather than "**This is test**".

**To sum up my question is, how to pass these HTML tags or whole HTML code via json from PHP to AJAX.**

Comment: why you don't use jquery's post and pass 'json' to the [dataType]? It's everything done for you to use!

Comment: Interesting but please tell me or show an example - what's the main difference between $.ajax and $.post in this case. I'm not sure but I don't think that's the problem in this case... I might be wrong, and if so please correct me and give a pure example of your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how `jQuery.ajax()` works.  You just need to tell it that `dataType: 'json'` (meaning that you're expecting JSON output from the server), and it takes care of the rest.  You don't need to use `jQuery.parseJSON()`.  The `success()` method will be given a JavaScript object representing the server response.

```
        success: function(output)
        {
            // output is a JS object here:
            alert(output.success);  // true

            // ...
        },
```

To get your HTML from that point, you would just access `output.src`.

Comment: Alright I'll remove $.parseJSON and change type to json, but how to communicate AJAX -> PHP and receive data which comes from AJAX side on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax request and receive an object(i.e. json already parsed) in your success call. eg

```
$.ajax(url, {
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output)
        {
            if(output.success == true)
            {
               obj_a.parents(".row").append(output.src);
               obj_a.attr("id", "rollBack");
               obj_a.text("Roll back");
            }
        },
```

if you can't change dataType you would call `$.parseJSON` on output

```
 function(output)
        {
            alert(output);
            var data = $.parseJSON(output);
            if(data.success == true)
            {
               obj_a.parents(".row").append(data.src);
               obj_a.attr("id", "rollBack");
               obj_a.text("Roll back");
            }
        },
```

Comment: I use type: 'post' - OK, i will change to json type but please tell me how to receive on server side in PHP data in json? i.e. when I use 'post' on the server side I call $_POST['someData']. But how can I do this with json type?

Comment: @lokatek `dataType` and `type` is not the same, set `dataType` to `json` leave `type` alone

Comment: but tell me how to receive this data on PHP side? $_GET['json'] or how?

Comment: @lokatek however you did before